# Cypress - pushing JSON rewrites the data

Tags: javascript, cypress

in Cypress I want to store some data into JSON file. The thing is, whenever I want to store new data, the old ones gets overwritten. Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks.

```js
cy.get('.form').find('.row').eq(20).find('.ng-untouched').then(opt_task => {
                if (opt_task[0].innerText) {
                  opt_task.push({opt_task_description: opt_task[0].innerText}) 

                } else if (opt_task[0].value) {
                  opt_task.push({opt_task_description: opt_task[0].value})
                }

                cy.writeFile(task_json, opt_task)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the flag `a+` to append the new results at the end of the json rather than replacing it.

```js
cy.writeFile(task_json, opt_task, { flag: 'a+' })
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but it still creates a new array in JSON, instead of inserting the data into the empty one that I have created before. Thus resulting in error "End of file expected" as seen on the picture here: https://prnt.sc/jAf_TDGwAh5r

Any idea how to work around it? Thank you.